# Blender Asset Browser and Folders full of Materials

Tags: materials, asset

Unsure of how to utilize this feature. Today I bought some set of PBR textures from FreePBR. I have set the filepath for assets to my assets folder containing the subfolders with the different materials and their respective maps.

I figured the asset browser was the tool for this, on top of all textures having a preview image included, seems like Blender should recognize a file full of textures and ya know, give me a little thumbnail preview of that material. Tutorial for asset browser all seem to only show how to sit there and make a goofy file full of random crap to add to a library to call up later. This is obviously not very useful, and I am not sure how else to ask or search for how to do the sensible thing with the asset browser.

I know Poliigon had something like an asset browser that worked specifically with their files, figured Blenders official thing would be much the same.

Any way to be able to browse a big folder of texture assets without making a file with a couple hundred dummy spheres where you have to hand-create each texture with node wrangling each folders contents respectively?

Comment: Hello. You don't need a hundred dummy spheres, just create the material. Blender will automatically create a preview sphere image for you ;-) There are [addons to batch import](https://blenderartists.org/t/assetlibrarytools-free-addon-to-speed-up-the-creation-of-blender-3-0-asset-browser-libraries/1317385) PBR materials and the image textures maps (diffuse, roughness map, normal map, etc) so you don't need to do this manually.